# Inconsistent pgfplot - spot the difference

Tags: pgfplots

This took forever to try reproduce, and I've no idea what is happening. The following,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
0.0 0.0
0.5 0.5
1.0 0.0
0.0 0.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\lb}{165581}
\newcommand{\ub}{165583}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-0.1, ymax=0.6,xmin=\lb,xmax=\ub],
        \foreach \x in {\lb, \lb+1} {
            \addplot+[no marks] table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}+\x, y index={1}] {data.dat};
        }  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-0.1, ymax=0.6,xmin=165581,xmax=165583],
        \foreach \x in {165581, 165582} {
            \addplot+[no marks] table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}+\x, y index={1}] {data.dat};
        }  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces,

[image: this]

Why are the plots not identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case you give `pgfplots` something that it needs to parse, and in the second case an integer. You can make them equal by making sure that in the first case there is also an integer. One way to achieve this is to replace `\lb+1` by `\the\numexpr\lb+1`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
0.0 0.0
0.5 0.5
1.0 0.0
0.0 0.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\lb}{165581}
\newcommand{\ub}{165583}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-0.1, ymax=0.6,xmin=\lb,xmax=\ub],
        \foreach \x in {\lb,\the\numexpr\lb+1} {
            \addplot+[no marks] table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}+\x, y index={1}] {data.dat};
        }  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-0.1, ymax=0.6,xmin=165581,xmax=165583],
        \foreach \x in {165581, 165582} {
            \addplot+[no marks] table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}+\x, y index={1}] {data.dat};
        }  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why the second case would be defined behaviour. The plot is wrong after all, the corner points of each triangle are the same.

Comment: @algae This is a good point. There are rounding errors. One can make the plots equal but with these large numbers one may it is not some easy to make the result "exact" it seems.

Comment: It is difficult when there is no explicit type definitions. The numbers used here are much smaller than a standard `int`.. As an aside, is there any work being doing to get something as good as pgfplots, but without the nasty language environment? IMO nothing else produces cleaner graphics, but it is a pity that we can't just write this stuff in regular C or something.

Comment: @algae You can produce data tables with C and then plot them. As far as I know, no major changes in the syntax are planned. Each method has advantages and downsides. (There is some discussion about the precision, but it is not clear where they will lead to.)

Comment: I see. Yes, if the memory issues and precision could be fixed i'd be happy.